# How to fix the Login remeber me function?

Tags: java, android-studio

when my function remeber me is checked, it only stored the username and not the password,
how to fix or change the whole function in order to have the possibility to store both username and password.

```
static String PASSWORD = "password";
        static String EMAIL = "email";
 mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email1);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password1);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        Remember=findViewById(R.id.remember_me);

        Remember.isChecked();
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("LoginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        /////////////////To get Stored Data/////////////////////////////////
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boolean isRemember=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("remember_me",false);
      if(isRemember){
            EMAIL=sharedPreferences.getString("EMAIL","email");
            PASSWORD=sharedPreferences.getString("PASSWORD","password");
            mEmail.setText(EMAIL);
            mPassword.setText(PASSWORD);
    Remember.setChecked(true);
  }
        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EMAIL= mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                PASSWORD = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email manquant.");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD)){
                    mPassword.setError("Mot de passe manquant.");
                    return;
                }
              
                }
                if(Remember.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("remember_me",true);
                    editor.putString("EMAIL",mEmail.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("PASSWORD",mPassword.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                }else {
                    editor.putString("EMAIL", "email");
                    editor.putString("PASSWORD", "password");
                    editor.commit();
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Your `passowrd` key it should be `password`
Better to store key in a static value
e.g

```
static String PASSWORD = "password";
static String EMAIL = "email";
```

and you can use them as

```
editor.putString(EMAIL, your_email);
editor.putString(PASSWORD, your_password);
```

Comment: I did what you said but it does not work. can you show me how will you do it please.

Comment: Are you using EMAIL and PASSWORD variable everywhere while reading from shared pref?

Comment: Yes I am using it everywhere

Comment: Post your updated code so that I can see what's wrong

Comment: I edited my first post code, you can see my code with your solution

Comment: ok your code looks fine. did you clear the cache? try to clear the cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233178/discussion-between-muhammad-ahmed-and-antoine).